# Fire-base Storage How to Duplicate/Copy Stored Image?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularfire, firebase-storage

I know [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) does not allow any method to duplicate the stored image. But we are creating an application where we allow the user to duplicate the record along with saved images. We are using anguar.js and angularfier and node.js, is there any way we can copy the image in storage by client side (angualar.js) or by server side (node.js) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no method in the Firebase Storage API to duplicate/copy an existing file. You will have to [download the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) and re-[upload it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

Alternatively you can (from your app server) call the [Google Cloud Storage API's copy command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy) and use that to create the copy.

Comment: The product was renamed to Cloud Storage for Firebase in March, to more clearly indicate that it's a wrapper around Cloud Storage. Firebase offers client-side SDK and a server-side security model. With these and other Firebase features, you can build secure uploads directly from apps and web sites. Without the Firebase additions this is not built into Google Cloud Storage.